# cakephp including two views on the home page

Tags: cakephp

I'm a cakephp and MCV newbie, so bear with me. I've been reading until my head exploded, but I'm not getting the big picture yet.

I have a TransactionsTable, TransactionsController with add() method, and an "add" view that outputs an "Add Transaction" form.

I have an AccountsTable, AccountsController with index() method, and an "index" view that outputs a list of Accounts.

What's the best way to include this form AND this list on the home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add the list into your add view then your really don't need two views. Here's a simple way of doing what you want though: In your add() method you can get the list of accounts by loading the Accounts table, then just pass that to your view.

In add() :

```
$this->loadModel('Account');
$articles = $this->Account->find(//Add whatever you use to produce the list here);
$this->set('articles', $articles);
```

Then just display the list as you did in your accounts/index page. You're essentially combining two views into one.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. It actually helped open up my overall understanding. I was able to implement what you suggested.

Comment: Well hopefully you enjoy your journey at being a CakePHP magician, also please mark the answer as accepted just for records and rep. :)